# Delete ZNode with plain text ACL

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I was using zkCli to try and understand digest ACLs a bit better and somehow created a ZNode I cannot delete. I ran this command:

```
[zk: host:2181(CONNECTED) 1] setAcl /test digest:test:test:crwda
```

And it worked. Now the ZNode shows the following ACL:

```
[zk: host:2181(CONNECTED) 12] getAcl /test
'digest,'test:test
: cdrwa
```

But now I cannot delete this ZNode. I have tried several variations of addauth but I keep getting the error "Authentication is not valid":

```
addauth digest test:test
addauth digest test:V28q/NynI4JI3Rk54h0r8O5kMug=
```

How the heck am I supposed to remove this ZNode?

Comment: getAcl shows the encoded pw, so you should have used `setAcl /test digest:test:V28q/NynI4JI3Rk54h0r8O5kMug=:crwda` for `addauth digest test:test` to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this in zkCli:

delete /test